Set the height of <div> based on the height of another <div> through css
I have two divs: a div with a Text Field and a div with a long list of items. My use case is to keep the search box (text field) at the top while the listContainer div can scroll if it contains a large number of items. Currently, the scroll bar is added to the entire parent div, so the search box is hidden as you scroll. I only need the scrollbar for the list container.
The problem is solved if I know the height of the search container and parent (listContainer height = parent height — searchContainer height). Is there a way to compute the height of the list container using CSS?


.parent {
  height: 100%
}

.searchContainer {}

.listContainer {
  height: 90%;
}
<div class="parent">
  <div class="searchContainer">
    <input placeholder="Enter search string">
  </div>
  <div class="listContainer">
    <div class="list-item">1</div>
    <div class="list-item">2</div>
    <div class="list-item">3</div>
    <div class="list-item">4</div>
    <div class="list-item">5</div>
    <div class="list-item">6</div>
    <div class="list-item">7</div>
    <div class="list-item">8</div>
    <div class="list-item">9</div>
    <div class="list-item">10</div>
    <div class="list-item">11</div>
    <div class="list-item">12</div>
    <div class="list-item">13</div>
    <div class="list-item">14</div>
    <div class="list-item">15</div>
    <div class="list-item">16</div>
  </div>
</div>




One way to solve this would be to position the .searchContainer absolutely within the parent container, and add some top padding to the listContainer to push it down below the input.


.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%
}

.searchContainer {
  position: absolute;
}

.listContainer {
  height: 100px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
<div class="parent">
  <div class="searchContainer">
    <input placeholder="Enter search string">
  </div>
  <div class="listContainer">
    <div class="list-item">1</div>
    <div class="list-item">2</div>
    <div class="list-item">3</div>
    <div class="list-item">4</div>
    <div class="list-item">5</div>
    <div class="list-item">6</div>
    <div class="list-item">7</div>
    <div class="list-item">8</div>
    <div class="list-item">9</div>
    <div class="list-item">10</div>
    <div class="list-item">11</div>
    <div class="list-item">12</div>
    <div class="list-item">13</div>
    <div class="list-item">14</div>
    <div class="list-item">15</div>
    <div class="list-item">16</div>
  </div>
</div>





My use case is to keep the search box (text field) at the top

Consider position:sticky;
MDN link for more info
Add
.searchContainer {
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
}

to your css and it will "stick" to the top.  If you don't want it to move at all, then tweak the top:0; setting.


.parent {
  height: 100%
}

.searchContainer {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.listContainer {
  height: 90%;
}
<div class="parent">
  <div class="searchContainer">
    <input placeholder="Enter search string">
  </div>
  <div class="listContainer">
    <div class="list-item">1</div>
    <div class="list-item">2</div>
    <div class="list-item">3</div>
    <div class="list-item">4</div>
    <div class="list-item">5</div>
    <div class="list-item">6</div>
    <div class="list-item">7</div>
    <div class="list-item">8</div>
    <div class="list-item">9</div>
    <div class="list-item">10</div>
    <div class="list-item">11</div>
    <div class="list-item">12</div>
    <div class="list-item">13</div>
    <div class="list-item">14</div>
    <div class="list-item">15</div>
    <div class="list-item">16</div>
  </div>
</div>




I see a few issues when minimizing the window. The list overlaps with the search box, and two scroll bars are added

"minimizing"?  ie moving to the taskbar?  Or just making very small?   Doesn't happen for me with the above snippet, but if it doesn't work for you and your specific implementation then don't use it.

This sticky method works for me. What browser and OS are you using, or is there something else in your code which is affecting the outcome?
